# After installing anaconda, python gives error "no module named numpy"

Tags: python, numpy, package, pip, anaconda

I installed anaconda and numpy but when I try to use them, it gives me this error message:

> Import error: no module named 'numpy'

Should I copy all the library files and paste in `\Python\Python35-32\Lib` address?

[image]

Comment: please put your error message in your question, written, not in a screenshot. i have updated it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple versions of python installed, and you are not invoking anaconda python. Try invoking:

```
c:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python
```